# StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Randomly I got an error **StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout**

I use StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.dll version 1.2.6 . Here is the piece of code for connect redis server

```
private static void ensureConnection()
        {

                        var configOptions = new StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions
                        {
                            ConnectTimeout = 5000,
                            ConnectRetry = 5,
                            SyncTimeout = 5000,
                            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                        };

                        configOptions.EndPoints.Add(host, port);

                        var conn = StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions);

                        redisConn = conn;

    }
```

Its working fine most of time but i got this connection error 2 or 3 times randomly in a day.

Comment: are you sure that redis is 100% up all the time and doesnt shutdown for some reason?

Comment: Yes, redis is up all the time